# Should I explicity terminate expired threads?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a thread pool with threads doing specific tasks. After the task is done, I let the run() method of a worker to terminate.

After this, should I explicitly kill the thread with sys.exit() ? I noticed that the worker thread persists in the background, even after the task is done.

What's the recommended way to purge old threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing `sys.exit` will quit the whole application. There is no need to do anything with a thread finished execution.

Fur further reference about stopping/killing a thread see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python).

Comment: Are the expired threads then automatically garbage-collected? I am assuming that since such a thread can still return is_alive() then it exists in the memory. In normal operation my program never calls sys.exit()

Comment: The thread object itself is not garbage collected as long as you have a reference to it. But the objects created in a thread get usually collected after a thread exists. But there are some cases when objects can't be collected, for example with cyclic dependencies. But this is a general problem and has nothing to do with threads.